# Storing a set of 10 2D arrays for X people

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, ms-word

Basically, I have a scraping function in VBA that scrapes information from ~ 10 different tables on different pages and stores them in 10 2D arrays.

I need to repeat this process for X number of people linked to an application, meaning I need 10 sets of 2D arrays for an unknown amount of people depending on the application.

What is the best way to approach designing this system. There cannot be more than 20 people linked to an application, but do I really need to globally create 200 empty arrays to store the information for a maximum case?

Also, how would I indicate in my scrape function to store a particular set of 10 2D arrays for a specific person, if my 2D array naming convention is as follows:

```
Application_Person1_Name()
Application_Person2_Name()
Application_Person3_Name()
```

If I use a for loop to iterate through each linked person and pass a string parameter such as "Person" + i in my scrape function, I cannot append it to the base array name of "Application_" because VBA does not support concatenation to refer to a variable name.

I'm quite stumped and was looking for some help with this. Anything is appreciated.

Comment: The `Value` in a Dictionary can be anything, even a 2-D array. So, I think your choice is basically between Dictionary and Collection. Read more here: http://analystcave.com/excel-vba-dictionary-arrays-and-other-data-structures/

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I find VBA's array implementation inflexible and limiting.  However, I imagine you can start with using an ordinary `String` instead of an array, thus reducing the problem to 10 Strings for X people, or a one-dimensional array.

If it were me, I would start with something like

```
Dim Application_Person_Names() as String
ReDim Application_Person_Names(10)
```

Initialise all Strings to a value which ***never*** appears in the values you're collecting.  I picked `vbCr`.

```
Dim i as Integer
...
For i = 0 to Ubound(Application_Person_Names)
   Application_Person_Names(i) = vbCr
next i
```

Then as you work through your documents,

```
Application_Person_Names(j) = Application_Person_Names(j) = Next_Name & vbcr
```

where `j` is the relevant group.

If you need to remove duplicates as you go along, you could do

```
If 0 = InStr(Application_Person_Names(j), vbCr & Next_Name & vbCr) then
   Application_Person_Names(j) = Application_Person_Names(j) = Next_Name & vbcr
End If
```

Once done, you are left with 10 strings containing zero or more names.  Provided the names are relatively small, the performance of the repeated concatenation `Application_Person_Names(j) = Application_Person_Names(j) & Next_Name & vbcr` should be good enough.

You can clean up a bit by removing the leading `vbCr` from each string

```
For i = 0 to Ubound(Application_Person_Names)
   Application_Person_Names(i) = Mid(Application_Person_Names(i), 2, Len(Application_Person_Names(i)) - 1)
next i
```

And then, if you really want, you can turn these into a real array using the VBA `Split` function.

```
Dim a() as String
...
a = Split(Application_Person_Names(...), vbCr)
```

One unfortunate feature of VBA arrays is that you cannot have an array of zero elements, thus the Split may fail if the string is empty.  However, having empty strings is fine.

Later, once you have something working, you want to try other features like a String Builder (faster concatenation) or Collections.

I hope this helps.